# How to pass user authentication through jitsi-meet external API

Tags: jitsi

I am building chat capability in my web application. I am using jitsi as our chat server. There can be 2-4 user in a video chat session. These session will be locked. Web application will initiate the chat and will control who can join the chat room.

I am trying to embed jitsi meet inside an web page using jitsi-meet
external API listed here
https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/doc/api.md .

Our jitsi-meet is not open to public and protected with XMPP
authentication. How can I pass the authentication information through
jitsi-meet API?

I also want to lock the conference room with password. Does jitsi-meet API
have this option?

I am new to this domain. So if you know a better solution please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is:
api.executeCommand('password', 'The Password');

Best way I am using with a php/mysql app is generating a room with a random name (usually complex) from the 1st user (the caller), protecting that room with a password and sending the rest of the users a message through the app so that they can connect to the same room with the first.

This way the first user is the end point and the rest connect to the room the first user made.

You should check the other users are online at the time the room is created. The only parameter is the room name which must at all times be unique. Maybe count participants after you enter. When the last user leaves the room, the room gets destroyed. So the users hold the room.

You can also send a mail instead of an internal message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add JWT token-based [authentication in jitsi](https://github.com/jitsi/lib-jitsi-meet/blob/master/doc/tokens.md) then you need to generate JWT token & pass it through Jitsi's external API, in this way:

```js
const options = {
   ...
   jwt: '<jwt_token>',
   ...
};
const api = new JitsiMeetExternalAPI(domain, options);
```

for more detail, you should checkout Jitsi's [iframe docs](https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/dev-guide/dev-guide-iframe/)